# Permitir acesso a outros diretórios com .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, htaccess, diretório

Tenho um site Wordpress instalado na raiz e um gerenciador de ordem de serviço em uma pasta chamada `/Sistema`.

O problema é que, quando digito `www.meudominio.com.br/sistema/`, está redirecionando para a **página 404** do Wordpress.

O `.htaccess` do Wordpress está assim:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

O que eu teria que fazer para conseguir acessar essa pasta pelo navegador?

Answer (score 1):

O .htaccess ainda não foi configurado pelo Wordpress.

Você precisa entrar no painel e acessar Configurações -> Links Permanentes e escolher qualquer uma das estruturas, menos a padrão (meudominio.com.br/?p=123).

Se o wordpress não conseguir criar o .htaccess sozinho ele vai mostrar o código na tela que você precisa colocar no arquivo.